# Accessing view from within ajax success() call

Tags: backbone.js, coffeescript

I have a backbone.js view which has the following ajax call:

```
BackboneDemo.Views.Projects.ProjectView extends Backbone.View

  demoFunction: () ->
    ...
    ...
    @collection.create(new_project_attributes,
      success: ->
        console.log @
        $('#' + @options.query_id).html('Saved successfully').delay(1500).fadeOut(500, -> $(@).remove())
```

The problem is, the `this` from inside the success call returns `DOMWindow`, not the view in which the `@options.query_id` is located. (Yes, `demoFunction` is bound to the view).

How can I access view attributes from within an AJAX `success()` call in Backbone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idiomatic CoffeeScript way would be to use a [fat arrow](http://coffeescript.org/#fat_arrow) to bind the callback function to the `this` that you want it to be:

> The fat arrow `=>` can be used to both define a function, and to bind it to the current value of `this`, right on the spot. This is helpful when using callback-based libraries like Prototype or jQuery, ...

So something like this:

```
@collection.create(new_project_attributes,
  success: =>
    console.log @
    $('#' + @options.query_id).html('Saved successfully').delay(1500).fadeOut(500, -> $(@).remove())
```

Looks like you want `this` to be the element that you're fading out in the inner callback so you'd leave that thin arrow (`->`) alone.

And a simple demo of the difference between `=>` and `->`: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/vGHrM/

Comment: That's useful stuff. I've not worked much with CoffeeScript, but every day I see something that makes me say, "man, I should start".

Comment: @Rob: Like most things, CoffeeScript has good things (such as `=>` and destructured assignment) and bad things (such being [sensitive to formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9014970/why-does-coffeescript-require-whitespace-after-map)). You can choose CoffeeScript in the "Panels" sidebar on jsfiddle.net if you want an easy way to play around with it, there's also the "try CoffeeScript"  translator on http://coffeescript.org/.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way (without calling some sort of "binding" helper function) is to just locally store a reference to the `this` you want to use:

```
demoFunction: () ->
    ...
    var self = this;
    @collection.create(attrs, success: ->
        // use self.options.query_id
        ...
```