# Why does CoffeeScript require whitespace after map?

Tags: coffeescript

This code

```
nums = [1..10].map (i) -> i*2
```

Runs

Whereas this

```
nums = [1..10].map(i) -> i*2
```

is broken

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason for this is that parentheses for a function call (invocation) are optional.  I find this a constant confusion in my own code and have a general policy of always including parentheses to make it clear.

In coffee script, if you leave out the parentheses it assumes that the argument list goes to the end of the line. Your first example coffee script is actually the same as this:

```
nums = [1..10].map((i) -> i*2)
```

where the first argument of the call to map is a function `(i)->i*2`

If you remove the space between the map and the (i) then coffee script implies parentheses around the rest of the line.  Your second example coffee script is actually the same as  this:

```
nums = [1..10].map(i)(-> i*2)
```

Here you can see that map is being called with `i` as the only argument and then coffee script is expecting the `map(i)` call to return a function which is then being called passing `->i*2` or to be more explicit `()->i*2` as an argument.

Given that coffee script is designed to remove the potential coding hazards of javascript, I think that it would have been much safer if they had not included this implied parenthesis.

Answer (score 4):

The `map(i)` in the second one is interpreted as a function call. The JavaScript comes out like this:

```
var nums;

nums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10].map(i)(function() {
  return i * 2;
});
```

and that doesn't make any sense because `map` doesn't return a function and there is no `i` defined.

In the first one, the space turns it into `[1..10].map((i) -> i*2)` so you end up calling `map` with a function as an argument; the JavaScript in this case looks like this:

```
var nums;

nums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10].map(function(i) {
  return i * 2;
});
```

Comment: I love CoffeeScript.  Don't get me wrong... but this type of whitespace issue irks me.  From a readability perspective, it looks like it shouldn't matter... but it does.  This is why whenever I come up with this perceived ambiguity, I often remove it and write: `map( (i) -> i*2 )` so that it can't be accidentally interpreted incorrectly.

Comment: I'll go one further than Brian, to avoid these sort of things my team and I have decided to not utilize CoffeeScript's ability to leave off the parens for function calls. I leave off the parens in `if` clauses and other places where javascript requires a predicate to be wrapped in parens. But I use them for all function calls. I write `() ->` rather than just `->`. For your instance, I would write it just like Brian, `...map( (i) -> i*2 )`; much more readable in my opinion.

Comment: I am not convinced about  those inner spaces in the parentheses, personally I'd write: `xs.map((x) -> x*2)`. Otherwise I agree with both of you, parentheses-less style looks cool when writing DSL-style code, but when writing "normal" code you end up having problems (this happens also in Ruby, for example). Using parenthenses has another advantage: you can write concatenable Ruby-style multi-line blocks which look pretty well (using `)` as there were `end`s).

Comment: @tokland: I too find the lack of an explicit close-block token problematic, especially with the two character indent that many people insist on using. I tend to factor my CS into tiny methods to avoid any nesting deeper than one level, same goes for callbacks, they're almost always named methods as CS's block structure gets confusing very fast. Maybe I'm just old school but I like braces for blocks.